# How to add .Net Framework 4, exist just 4.5+

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, installation

I have program which required .Net Framework 4.0
When I try make Installer by VS i can`t choose 4.0 in prerequisite,
I have just 4.5.2+ or 3.5 SP1 to choose.
[image]

Comment: This question is not belongs to SO. .NET versions backward-compatible. Anyway, if you need 4th version, download and install in your machine .

Comment: have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

Comment: This requires a bootstrapper package.  This does end somewhere, VS2013 is the last VS version where you can still expect to have one for 4.0.  It otherwise does very little, just checks if it is installed and if not fails the install and points the user to the download location.  People that still run XP need to know how to keep their machine updated by themselves.  Do keep in mind that you cannot forcibly downgrade a machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it no longer appears as an option because [Microsoft no longer supports .NET Framework 4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/). But do note that .NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6, and 4.6.1 are in-place upgrades for .NET Framework 4.0, so you should be able to use them in your installer without any issues.

> #### Will I need to recompile/rebuild my applications to make use of .NET 4.5.2, 4.6 or 4.6.1?
>
> .NET 4.5.2, 4.6 and 4.6.1 are compatible, in-place updates on top of .NET 4, .NET 4.5, and .NET 4.5.1. This means that applications built to target any of these previous .NET 4.x versions will continue running on .NET 4.5.2 without change. No recompiling of apps is necessary.

Comment: I was try on VS 2015 and it`s work. You was right! Thank You!